# A du equivalent for use on a Git repository managed by GVFS

Tags: windows, git, gvfs

I am researching into using [GVFS](https://github.com/Microsoft/VFSForGit)

One thing I noticed right away - do not run the [du](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/du) tool from sysinternals on such a repo - it will take ages to complete.

I suppose it has to do with how the file size is obtained when GVFS is at play. So, my question is - if I still want to be able to compute the real size of a folder within such a repo (or the repo itself) - how do I do it sanely?

Comment: What does"the real size" even mean in this context?  Size in a git pack can be almost anything, git gets its storage efficiency in many ways that nobody really has to care about much, but they do make the relation between packed size and size in a check out a bit hard to track.

Comment: The real size of a folder is the sum of the sizes of the files under it recursively. It could be also reported as size on disk (taking into account the sector size or whatever). The thing is that with GVFS files are not present on the client file system until requested. Please, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/git/git-at-scale for more information.